# Confusion in looping nested dictionaries python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to create a dictionary with a nested dictionary. All the values that I am working with came from 3 different lists (same length).

The final result should look like:

```
d = {SP1: {TS1:[values here], TS2:[values here]}, SP2:{TS1:[other values]}}
```

the main problem I'm facing is that the lists should be filtered because they have duplicated values:

```
# this should be the first key of the dictionary (SP1, SP2..), not repeated
sp = [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 9, 12, 14, 15]

# this it the first inner key (TS1, TS2..), not repeated but coherent to the sp list values
ts = [2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3]

# these values should go inside the list of each TS key
sim = [14.4953689575, 14.2694330215, 14.3503818512, 14.2953929901, 14.1140880585, 13.9398431778, 13.8227128983, 13.9122915268, 13.8505115509, 14.3296766281, 15.0080194473, 14.7962331772, 14.3174362183, 14.0135688782, 13.8948440552, 13.8888025284, 13.7929182053, 13.7562999725, 13.7984809875, 14.4026594162, 14.8861970901, 14.7377538681, 14.853559494, 14.7751989365, 14.603521347, 14.4809532166, 14.4053077698, 14.5300836563, 14.4450139999, 14.8226003647]
```

I tried something like that:

```
d = {}
for i, j in enumerate(sp):
    d[j] = {}
    for i in ts:
        if ts[i] not in d[j]:
            d[j] = {ts[i] : []}
            d[j][ts[i]].append(sim[i])
```

but the output is wrong because it is creating bot `TS` key and `sim` values from only the last one taken.

This is the expected final dictionary:

```
d = {
2: {2: [14.4953689575, 14.8861970901]}, 
3: {3: [14.2694330215, 14.7377538681]}, 
4: {3: [14.3503818512, 14.853559494]}, 
5: {3: [14.2953929901, 14.7751989365]}, 
7: {2: [14.1140880585, 14.603521347]}, 
9: {1: [13.9398431778, 14.4809532166], 3: [13.8227128983, 14.4053077698]}, 
12: {1: [13.9122915268, 14.5300836563]}, 
14: {1: [13.8505115509, 14.4450139999]}, 
15: {3: [14.3296766281, 14.8226003647]}, 
16: {2: [15.0080194473]}, 
17: {1: [14.7962331772]}, 
18: {1: [14.3174362183]}, 
19: {1: [14.0135688782]}, 
20: {1: [13.8948440552]}, 
21: {1: [13.8888025284]}, 
22: {1: [13.7929182053]}, 
23: {2: [13.7562999725]}, 
24: {2: [13.7984809875]}, 
25: {2: [14.4026594162]}
}
```

Thanks for any hint

Comment: To remove dublicates use `set`. i.e. `var = list(set(var))`

Comment: You have two `i` values; your inner loop `i` masks the outer loop `i`. Why have the `enumerate()` loop at all?

Comment: Python aim to readability, so please use meaningful variable names. It' easier for us to help you.

Comment: And you replace `d[j]` each time. Perhaps you meant to use `d[j][ts[i]] = []` instead?

Comment: thanks for the feedbacks. Maybe the question is not well explained. In the meanwhile I edited it with the final result I am looking for. And I'll try to explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inner_dicts = [{k: [v]} for k, v in zip(ts, sim)]

result = {}

for key, value in zip(sp, inner_dicts):
    result[key] = result.get(key, {})

    for inner_k, inner_v in value.items():
        result[key][inner_k] = list(set(result[key].get(inner_k, []) + inner_v))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Almost the final result. That's my fault because the question is not super explicit. For example the outer `9` key should have 2 nested keys, `1` and `3` because `9` is repeated twice in the `sp` list. I edited the original question with the final result. Thanks again

Comment: @matteo i've updated my answer with solution that fits your requirements

Comment: @matteo , you are welcome. Btw if my solution is not clear enough - i can explain it line by line

Comment: yep, it is clear even if I'd never come to a solution like that ;)